# Porque el controlador no me direcciona a la vista de Registro utilizando Ajax

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

Estoy trabajando con java, HTML en jsp y JavaScript directamente en la pagina, Tengo una pagina de registro de los datos de un usuario y son enviados atraves de JavaScript por medio de Ajax al controlador y  el controlador o Servlet los recibe cada vez que se haga click al botón llegando a devolver una respuesta si el correo esta registrado en la base de datos o no a la vista de registro,  por medio de un alias dentro de la consulta si hay mas de un correo o no registrado en la bd, si el alias es cero en este caso no hay correos registrados y me debería de enviar a otra pagina para iniciar sesión que esta misma pagina se encuentra dentro de la carpeta web-inf pero no me hace ese direccionamiento no se porque y el direccionamiento esta bien ya que si creo otra vista y otro Servlet me funciona ese mismo direccionamiento donde me da a entender que es la función Ajax que lo esta afectando  y si hay mas de un valor es porque hay mas correos en la base de datos con ese correo  y en este caso me manda la respuesta otra vez a la vista y por medio de JavaScript pongo una alerta que diga que el correo suministrado ya esta Registrado.

## codigo de la vista

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>RegistroCrearCuenta</title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="Public/Estilos/style.css">-->
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo="> 
    <script src="Public/bootstrap/bootstrap-5.3.0-alpha1-dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="Public/Jquery/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head>



<body id="bodyResgistroC">

    <main>
       
        <div id="divContainer2">
            <div id="divFormulario2">

                <form class="formulario" action="controladorCrearCuenta" method="post" id="miFormulario">
                    <div id="tituloForm">
                        <div id="iconoForm">
                            <!--el mismo error de la imagen-->
                            <img src="Public/imgs/logoQ1.png" alt="logo" width="70px" height="70px">

                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h1>Farmacit</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            
                            
                            
                        </div>
                            
                        
                    </div>
                    <div id="divInputsG">

                        <div>

                            <div id="plbIngresar">
                                
                                <h2>Crear una cuenta</h2>

                            </div>
                               <div class="divInputsC">

                                <div class="cajaInps">
                                    <div>
                                        <label for="cajaInps">Nombre</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--<input type="hidden" name="fIdPersona" value="0"> es inesesario enviar este dato al controlador ya que va en auto Incremento--> 
                                    <input type="text" name="fNombrePersona" placeholder="Sus nombres" class="divAB" id="nombreP" required>
                                </div>

                                <div class="cajaInps">
                                    <div>
                                        <label for="cajaInps">Apellido</label>

                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" name="fApellidoPersona" placeholder="Sus apellidos" class="divAB" id="apellidoP" required>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="divGid">
                                <div class="divIdentificacion">

                                    <div class="labelid">
                                        <label for="labelid">Identificacion</label>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cajasId">
                                        <input type="number" class="inputId" name="fIdentificacionPersona"
                                            placeholder="Su identificacion" id="documentoP" required>

                                    </div>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="divGid">
                                <div class="divIdentificacion">

                                    <div class="labelid">
                                        <label for="labelid">Correo</label>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cajasId">
                                        <input type="email" class="inputId" name="fCorreoPersona"
                                               placeholder="Su correo"  id="inputCorreo"   required>

                                    </div>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="divGid">
                                <div class="divIdentificacion">

                                    <div class="labelid">
                                        <label for="labelid">Telefono</label>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cajasId">
                                        <input type="number" class="inputId" name="fTelefonoPersona"
                                            placeholder="Su Telefono" id="telefonoP" required>

                                    </div>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="divInputsC2">

                            <div class="cajaInps">
                                <div>
                                    <label for="cajaInps" >Contraseña</label>
                                </div>

                                <input type="password" placeholder="Su Contraseña" name="fContrasenaPersona" class="divAB" id="inputContrasena" required autocomplete="new-password">

                            </div>

                            <div class="cajaInps">
                                <div>
                                    <label for="cajaInps">Confirmar contraseña</label>

                                </div>
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Confirmar" class="divAB" id="inputConfirmarContrasena" required >
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        
                        <div id="divTerminos">
                            <!--el checkbox cuando no esta marcado el java script le agrega una clase-->                                                                                                                                                        
                            
                            <input type="checkbox" id="aceptarTerminos"  onchange="manipularCheckbox();" required >   
                          
                            <a href="#"  id="aTerminos" > Aceptar los términos y condiciones </a>
 
                        </div>
                        
                       
                    </div>
                    <div class="divButtonIn">
                        
                        <button class="buttonIngresarF" type="button"  name="fAccion" style="font-family: inherit; font-size: 18px;" onclick="validarCorreo();" id="mibtnC">
                                <h3>Registrar</h3> 
                        </button>
                    </div>

                 </form>   
            </div>

        </div>

</body>

</html>
```

## el Script :

```
 function validarCorreo() {
                             
                                
                            console.log(" Dentre a la funcion validarCorreo");
                                

                            
                             !(function(window, document) {//Esta es una función IIFE que toma window y document como argumentos, que son objetos globales. y se utliza para encapsular las variables
//                                   
                                  
                                    let nombre = document.getElementById("nombreP").value;
                                    let apellido = document.getElementById("apellidoP").value;
                                    let identificacion = document.getElementById("documentoP").value;
                                    let correo = document.getElementById("inputCorreo").value;
                                    let telefono = document.getElementById("telefonoP").value;
                                    let contrasena = document.getElementById("inputContrasena").value;
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                     let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();// se encarga de la comunicacion entre la otra vista enviar y recibir la respuesta 
                            
                                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

                                        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {

                                            let respuesta = xhr.responseText;// obtiene la respuesta  

                                            console.log(" La respuesta es ::::: "+ respuesta+" ______------ final de la respuesta ");


                                            if (respuesta === "true") {

                                                window.alert("El correo sumistrado ya esta Registrado, debes cambiarlo.");

                                     
                                            }else if (respuesta === "false") {

                                                console.log("el correo no esta Registrado");
//                                                xhr.abort();

                                            } else {

                                                console.log("Error en la consulta");
//                                             

                                            }
                                        }
                                    };
                            
                                        
                                    xhr.open("POST", "controladorCrearCuenta", true); // se envia el correo por medio de la url a controlador 
                                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                                    xhr.send("fNombrePersona="+nombre+"&fApellidoPersona="+apellido+"&fIdentificacionPersona=" + identificacion +"&fCorreoPersona=" + correo +"&fTelefonoPersona=" + telefono +"&fContrasenaPersona=" + contrasena);


                                    console.log(correo+" EEEEEEEEEEL CORREO ");
                                 
                            
                                    
                                event.preventDefault(); // Previene el comportamiento predeterminado del botón 


                                })(window, document);
                            

                            
                        }
```

## codigo en el controlador en el metodo Post:

```
  @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
//    Correo{
       
            try {
                
                //nota los names de los input y al momentos de enviar los datos en ajax deben ser iguales dentro la vista 
             
                
               
                
                
          
                
            String elCorreo = request.getParameter("fCorreoPersona");
            
            
         

            System.out.println("el correoooooooooooooooooooooooooo es : " + elCorreo );
            String consulta = " SELECT COUNT(*) as miAliasCount From Persona WHERE correoPersona = ? ;"; // el as count se utiliza para que a la hora de aceder al resultado sea mas legible o para poderlo manipular como un identificador un alias en en si 

            PreparedStatement sql = Conexion.conectar().prepareStatement(consulta);
            sql.setString(1, elCorreo);


            ResultSet elResultado =  sql.executeQuery();
            

           
            if (elResultado.next()) {
                
                
                int count = elResultado.getInt("miAliasCount");// accedemos y guardamos el valor en una variable 
                
                
                System.out.println(count+" -- resultado bd de count  ");
                if (count > 0) {
                    // El correo ya está registrado
                 
                    String mensaje = "true";
                 // Establece el tipo de contenido de la respuesta
                    response.setContentType("text/plain");

                 // Escribe el mensaje en la respuesta
                     response.getWriter().write(mensaje);
                     
                     System.out.println(mensaje+"en texto plano");

                    
                } else {
                    
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/Registro.jsp").forward(request, response);// nose porque no hace este direccionamiento a la vista de Registro 
                    
                    // El correo no esta registrado 
                    String mensaje = "false";
                    
                    // Establece el tipo de contenido de la respuesta
                    response.setContentType("text/plain");

                    // Escribe el mensaje en la respuesta
                    response.getWriter().write(mensaje);
                    
                  
                    
                    System.out.println(mensaje+" Este es el Mensaje  ");
//                
    
                    //Capturar los datos 
                    
                    String nombrePersona = request.getParameter("fNombrePersona");
                    String apellidoPersona = request.getParameter("fApellidoPersona");
                    String identificacionPersona = request.getParameter("fIdentificacionPersona");
                    String correoPersona = request.getParameter("fCorreoPersona");
                    String telefonoPersona = request.getParameter("fTelefonoPersona");
                    String contrasenaPersona = request.getParameter("fContrasenaPersona");
         
                    
                    
                    
                    System.out.println("datos en dopost");
                 
                    System.out.println(nombrePersona);
                    System.out.println(apellidoPersona);
                    System.out.println(correoPersona);
                    System.out.println(telefonoPersona);
                    System.out.println(contrasenaPersona);
                    
                    
                    // se envian los datos a otro Metodo para tener orden
                    insertarDatos(request,response, nombrePersona, apellidoPersona, identificacionPersona, elCorreo, telefonoPersona, contrasenaPersona);
//              

                }
                
                
            }else {
              // no se encontraron resultados
                System.out.println("No se encontraron resultados al verificar el correo");
         
            }
            
        } catch (Exception error) {
            
            System.err.println("error con la consulta "+error.getLocalizedMessage());
            
        }
        
        processRequest(request, response);

      
    }
```

[Estructura de los archivos aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J2AT.png)

los valores devueltos por la base de datos están bien y al momento de mostrar la alerta con JavaScript lo hace también bien ya que se activa y va al controlador y se devuelve y muestra la alerta pero si el correo no esta registrado se queda estático al momento de darle click al boton que en este caso seria la respuesta "false" y no me hace el direccionamiento y en las dos consolas que tengo no se ven errores con respecto a la función Ajax, si alguien me puede ayudar, le agradecería mucho, gracias.